# a.m or p.m. time format when recording record

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

good evening,

I need to record the date and time in a table but with the format (a.m. or p.m),

see that there is a point in the middle of a and m

I am trying with:

```
insert into fechadia (fecha,id )VALUES (to_date('14/05/2021 10:01:45 a.m.','DD/MM/YYYY hh:mi:ss a.m.'),'4')

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS a.m.';
```

and I get the error:
ORA-01855: am / a.m. or pm / p.m. necessary

if i remove the dot if it works, but it saves the record as AM, and not as a.m.

```
 insert into fechadia (fecha,id )VALUES (to_date('14/05/2021 10:01:45 am','DD/MM/YYYY hh:mi:ss a.m.'),'4')
```

Outcome:
05/14/2021 10:01:45 AM

desired value:
05/14/2021 10:01:45 a.m.

this value with point is important because the values ​​arrive as (a.m.)
I will appreciate any help.

***Informacion adicional:
la columna tiene el tipo de datos DATE

thank,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, dates are not stored as formatted strings, with "a.m." or "AM". These filters are only applied at the time the data is *processed*, to convert to or from the binary date data type. Additionally, since you are using an explicit format filter in your `to_date` function call, the value of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is irrelevant.

The error you are getting indicates that there is something off about your format string: something about the incoming data isn't matching up correctly, but I was unable to reproduce it. Is it possible that some rows have different formats? If you can't get the filter to work any other way, you could modify the text as it is inserted to something that works by removing all of the dots:

```
-- remove dots from a.m. or p.m.
insert into fechadia (fecha,id) VALUES (to_date(replace('14/05/2021 10:01:45 a.m.','.'),'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mi:ss am'),'4');
```

The point is to get your data inserted. Once it is in the table, then just use the appropriate filters when you select your data (i.e. "a.m.") and you shouldn't have any problems:

```
-- select a date data type and format with a.m.
select to_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mi:ss a.m.') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYYHH:MI:SSA.M.') 
----------------------------------------- 
07/07/2021 03:50:24 a.m.                  

-- convert a string with "pm" to a data data type and back to a formatted string with "p.m."
select to_char(to_date('07/07/2021 10:10:10 pm','DD/MM/YYYY hh:mi:ss am'),'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mi:ss a.m.') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('07/07/202110:10:10PM','DD/MM/YYYYHH:MI:SSAM'),'DD/MM/YYYYHH:MI:SSA.M.') 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
07/07/2021 10:10:10 p.m.
```